# ¿Cómo podría centrar una Tabla con Css?

Tags: html, css, html-tabla

Estoy realizando unas tablas con diferentes estilos y debo realizar una en HTML que quedé algo parecido a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo algo ya parecido, pero aún no he podido centrarla de esa forma, si alguien podría ayudarme se lo agradezco.

Adjunto el código

```css
    .table-center{
        text-align: start;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    .table-center td{
        padding-right: 50px;
    }
    .center-title{
        text-align: center;
        background-color: rgb(31, 146, 60);
    }
```

```html
<div id="tabla4" >
            <div id="titulo4" class="center-title">
                <h3><strong>FACTOR DE RIESGO</strong></h3>
            </div>
            <div>
                <table class="table-center">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>X1</td>
                            <td>Factor de Liquidez</td>
                            <td>0.07</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>X2</td>
                            <td>Factor de Rentabilidad</td>
                            <td>0.04</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Elimina `display: block;` de la clase `table-center`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, como en el comentario, borra `display: block`. Pero el CSS se puede reducir y mejorar aún más:

```
.table-center{
  margin: auto;
}

.table-center td{
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.center-title{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(31, 146, 60);
}
```

No relacionado, pero evite anidar `strong` dentro `h3`:

```
<div id="tabla4" >
  <div id="titulo4" class="center-title">
    <h3>FACTOR DE RIESGO</h3>
  </div>
<div>
  <table class="table-center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>X1</td>
        <td>Factor de Liquidez</td>
        <td>0.07</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>X2</td>
        <td>Factor de Rentabilidad</td>
        <td>0.04</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comprueba que `<div>` y `</div>` estén en el mismo número!

**https://jsfiddle.net/h7pec5fz/**

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google `:)`